# understanding python inner function .how does this works?

Tags: python, design-patterns, decorator

```
def prefix_factory(prefix):
    def prefix_printer(text):
        print(f"{prefix}: {text}")
    return prefix_printer
```

Now lets execute the below line.

```
# First time we are executing this
debug = prefix_factory('DEBUG') 

# Second time we are executing as
debug('Hello world')
```

## First time we are executing this

1st execution or assignment of function to the variable debug is assigned the value "DEBUG". My understanding is this is how it has to be executed.

ideally inner function prefix_printer(text) - gets defined inside prefix_factory()
'return prefix_printer' should get an error, stating that text is not available or text is missing.

## Second time we are executing as

debug('hello world ') - 2nd execution of the function reference.
The question for the second execution is, I am assuming 'hello world' should be considered as a value for the prefix. and text should be blank as we don't call prefix_printer in the return statement with any value. Hence it has to be '' empty string.  I am coming from c, C++ background.

My question is, it's the same piece of code 1st-time prefix is assigned,
but during the 2nd execution debug('Hello world') it behaves differently. How is it possible,  please clarify in detail how this works?

Comment: This is an exercise on nested functions, but does not deal with decorators at all. It is true that one of the most popular ways of defining decorators is using nested functions similar to this - but the inner functions should take a callable object (the one to be decorated) as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, i might be a bit confused but this is **not** actually how the decorator pattern in Python is used. For a decorator it actually has to decorate or wrap a function, for example `@dec my_func(): # so on`

Comment: updated the question accordingly. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: The _first time_ you don't execute the inner function, you define (with a closure through the outer function) and return it. Only the _second time_ you execute it. In Python functions are first class objects.

Answer (score 0):

When `debug = prefix_factory('DEBUG')` is executed, variable `debug` is assigned the *return value* from calling function `prefix_factory('DEBUG')`. It is *not* assigned the value "DEBUG" as you said. And what is this return value?

Function `prefix_factory` returns `prefix_printer`, which is a function nested within `prefix_factory`. Moreover, `prefix_printer` references a variable, `prefix`, which is defined in the outer, enclosing function. When `prefix_factory` returns a nested function, `prefix_printer`, that references a variable defined in the *nesting* function, that returned function is known as a [*closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). Even though we have now returned from the call to `printing_factory`, the closure function `prefix_printer`, which has now been assigned to variable `debug`, still has a reference to the value of variable `prefix` as it existed at the time `prefix_factory` was called.

Subsequently, when you execute `debug('Hello World')`, because `debug` evaluates to our `prefix_printer` closure , this is equivalent to calling function `prefix_printer('Hello World')` with variable `prefix` initialized to 'DEBUG'.